# MySQL REPLACE doesn't work

Tags: mysql, replace

I use this to replace `\"` with `"` :

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, '\"', '"')
```

That query returns `0 row(s) affected` and nothing happens.

What is wrong this this query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape your backslash:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, '\\"', '"')
```

Answer (score 1):

The backslash charecter is escape character in MySQL so you need to escape it itself like this:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, '\\"', '"')
```

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
REPLACE(`post_content`, '\\"', '"')
```